# Вывод текущей команды в spool файл SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Во время загрузки пакетов в БД *Oracle* в *SQL*Plus* устанавливаю spool файл для логгирования результатов, но текст текущей (выполняемой) команды не записывается в данный spool файл. Как вывести в spool файл не только результат выполнения, но и текст команды?

Сейчас выводит к примеру:

```
Java created.

No errors.

Package created.

Package created.

No errors.

Package created.
```

И не совсем понятно к какой процедуре относится данный результат.
Команд много и список получается достаточно большим.

Answer (score 2):

Прямой ответ на вопрос:

> Как вывести в spool файл не только результат выполнения но и текст команды?

После завершающих символов "/" (slash) или ";" (sqlterminator), команда выполняется, но до начала ввода следующей команды, текст команды хранится в буфере и может быть выведен командой `L[IST]`. Если вывод желателен только в spool файл, то предварительно надо выключить вывод в терминал `SET TERM[OUT] OFF`.  Например:

```
prompt #### creating package myPkg
create or replace package myPkg as 
...
end;
/ 
set termout off
list
show errors
set termout on
```

Если нужна более привычная последовательность, текст команды и затем результат выполнения, то удобней использовать команду `R[UN]`, которая выведет содержимое буфера и затем выполнит команду. Завершение ввода команды в буфер достигается вводом символа "." (period) на новой строке:

```
create or replace package myPkg as i int; end;
2  .
run
  1* create or replace package myPkg as i int; end;

Package created.
```

---

Другой подход. Я делаю так:

Каждый *user object* определяю в отдельный .sql файл. 
Загружаю и компилирую с *make* и в *makefile* указываю необходимые зависимости от других объектов.

Содержимое *makefile* (здесь для примера только фрагмент для пакетов):

```
UOBJS = testPkg anotherPkg 
SQLP = sqlplus
LOGON = sh/sh@oradb
SQLPFLAGS = -l -s $(LOGON)

.PHONY: uobj $(UOBJS)
uobj: $(UOBJS) $(MAKEFILE)
$(UOBJS): $(UOBJS:=.lis)

# так можно вручную определить зависмости
testPkg.lis: anotherPkg.lis

%.lis: %.sql $(MAKEFILE)
    @echo "############################################################## START $<"
    @{ $(SQLP) $(SQLPFLAGS) $(CONNSTR) @$<; echo $(@:.lis=)=$$?; } | cat > $@
    @if grep -e"^Errors" -e"^ORA-" $@ > /dev/null; \
    then \
        touch -r $< -d '-1 second' $@; \
        cat -s $@; exit 3; \
    else \
        echo -e "*** $(SQLP)=ENDOK $(@:.lis=) *** \n"; \
    fi
```

Вывод в консоль без ошибки :

```
$ make
############################################################### START testPkg.sql
*** sqlplus=ENDOK testPkg ***
```

В логе .lis можно поздне посмотреть, что и в какой ревизии было скомпилировано:

```
$ cat testPkg.lis

Package created.

  1  create or replace package testPkg as
  2      procedure termout (context varchar2, message varchar2);
  3      function myfunc (par varchar2) return varchar2;
  4* end testPkg;
No errors.

Package body created.

  1  create or replace package body testPkg as
  2      procedure termout (context varchar2, message varchar2) is
  3      begin null; end;
  4      function myfunc (par varchar2) return varchar2 is
  5      begin null; end;
  6* end testPkg;
No errors.
testPkg=0
```

Вывод в консоль, если ошибка:

```
$ make
############################################################### START testPkg.sql

Package created.

  1  create or replace package testPkg as
  2      procedure termout (context varchar2, message varchar2);
  3      function myfunc (par varchar2) return varchar2;
  4* end testPkg;
No errors.

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

  1  create or replace package body testPkg as
  2      procedure termout (context varchar2, message varchar2) is
  3      begin null; error here; end;
  4      function myfunc (par varchar2) return varchar2 is
  5      begin null; end;
  6* end testPkg;
Errors for PACKAGE BODY TESTPKG:
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/23     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "HERE" when expecting one of
         the following:
         := . ( @ % ;
         The symbol ":=" was substituted for "HERE" to continue.

testPkg=0
../../makefile:53: recipe for target 'testPkg.lis' failed
make: *** [testPkg.lis] Error 3
```

После устранения причины ошибки, компиляция продолжается с текущего объекта, а не перекомпилируются всё заново.

PS: В настояшее время переделаваю на *gradle*, но из-за специфики текущего проекта ещё не закончил и не могу предоставить работающий пример. Так же такие пункты, как: учитывать depedences считывая их с БД, стоят ещё на "сделать завтра" листочке.

Comment: Это интересно - впервые вижу использование `make` для `SQL`. Если еще интересно, то можно посмотреть на [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)...

Comment: @MaxU Почему нет? Лежит же на любой машине, незамысловат и надёжен. Ну как тут пройти мимо.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вывод всей команды, например `CREATE PACKAGE BODY` может оказаться очень большим и страшным, я делаю так: создаю главный `.sql` файл:

```
prompt **********************************
prompt RUN FILE core.sql
prompt **********************************

set serveroutput on

prompt Установка пакета ...
@@файл1.sql
prompt Установка представления ...
@@файл2.sql
```

И разношу команды по файлам по небольшим группам.